# Correct way to display current date/time in iOS app and keep it up to date

Tags: objective-c

I'm wondering this primarily out of the theory/performance side of things, but if I needed to display the current date/time in a UILabel or something, and then keep it up to date (say, down to the minute), what is the most correct way to do so?

I've seen various examples online of "clock" apps that basically just have a recursive method that runs with a 1 second delay between invocations.  Another option would be to create a repeatable timer and add it to the run loop.  There are probably a variety of other ways to do this as well.  Is there one way that is better than the others?

Comment: Any reason the date/time displayed in the iOS status bar isn't good enough?

Comment: It is, I'm really just asking this out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive method is not a great idea.

Use `NSTimer` approach. Create the repeating timer in `viewDidAppear` and `invalidate` the timer in `viewDidDisappear` (to avoid retain cycle, a.k.a. strong reference cycle). For example, assuming you have a `timer` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

You would then schedule and invalidate the timer as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}

- (void)handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // update your label here
}
```

If you don't release and/or `invalidate` the timer, it will maintain a strong reference to your controller and you can end up with a strong reference cycle. And you cannot resolve this strong reference cycle in `dealloc` (because `dealloc` is not called until the controller has no more strong references; the presence of a repeating `NSTimer` that has not been invalidated will prevent `dealloc` from ever getting called), which is why we do it in `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: Can you explain how that approach avoids retain cycles?

Comment: @chinabuffet See expanded answer.